# WebView is not opening webpages but browser is (ERROR: Web page not available)

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm creating an Android application (Android 2.3.3) that has a header, a footer and a WebView between both. The problem is that the WebView is not opening any webpage. (NOTE: I'm running the app on an emulator).

I tried opening webpages using the Android browser and the webpages are opened correctly. I also tried:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

And the code works correctly (opens the page in the browser).

I've been working with www.google.com and with a domain of my own, I've also been working with the ip adress of both web pages (for google 72.14.204.147 and for my own, the ip of my own dev server).

Also, before the most popular answer is written, I already have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` before the application tag.

I'm adding the code before anyone asks for it:

The activity java file:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

//Global Variables
WebView mainWebView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    loadActivityViews();

    mainWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mainWebView.loadUrl("www.google.com");
    mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
}

/** Loads all global views of the Activity */
private void loadActivityViews(){
    mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.index_main_web_view);
} 

//Internal Classes

/*
 * MyWebView Class
 * 
 * Forces links to open in the same webView
 * Handles the back button.
 * */

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent(WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && view.canGoBack()) {
            view.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.shouldOverrideKeyEvent(view, event);
    }
}
}
```

The android Manifest:
(NOTE: it has "android.permission.INTERNET" before the application tag)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pixable.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

the main.xml (I don;t think its important, but I'm adding it just in case)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/index_main_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/index_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#000000" >

            ... My header butons ...

        </RelativeLayout>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/index_main_web_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/index_header"
            android:layout_above="@+id/index_botom_layout" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/index_botom_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            ... My Footer Butons ...

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your issue is you're not prepending the URL with `http://`. I bet you `http://www.google.com` works.

Comment: Solved the problem, thank you. I was expecting something more complex.